# How to insert word document into sql server and download it into my drive? (visual studio c# windows application)

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2013

can any one suggest a code to insert word document to SQL database and download it from SQL database.(code should be visual studio c# windows application)

Thank you

Comment: I would suggest you to upload the  doc in the server n then the path to  be saved in the sql so that when need to be downloaded it can be done with the path

Answer (score 1):

Read the word document as byte array and store that as blob data in database.
For downloading read the byte array and stream the output as file with .doc extension

Comment: I had inserted the document but each doc I inserted is in the same format as 0x00000001

Comment: is there anything you can suggest me ?

Comment: Why do you mind about data stored in the table. You can retrieve back and check the data. The file that you stored will be back as you expected.

Comment: Other than blob data (Var Binary) you don't have options for inserting a file directly into a database.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have this table schema and you are using local sql db:

```
CREATE TABLE [FileTable1]
(
    [filePath] VARCHAR(100),
    [data] VARBINARY(MAX)
)
```

Here is the code to Insert:

```
static void InsertFile(string filename)
{   
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=(localdb)\\v11.0 ; Initial Catalog = {your db name}; Integrated Security = SSPI");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO FileTable1 VALUES (@filePath, @data)", conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filePath", Path.GetFileName(filename));
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

here is the code to insert:

```
string filetoInsert = @"C:\Temp\Test1.docx"; 
InsertFile(filetoInsert);
```

you can then retrieve it from database, like so:

```
static byte[] ReadFile(string filename)
{   
     SqlConnection conn= new SqlConnection("Server=(localdb)\\v11.0 ; Initial Catalog = {your db name}; Integrated Security = SSPI");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM FileTable1 WHERE filePath=@filePath", conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filePath", filename);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    rdr.Read();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    long startIndex= 0;
    const int readSize= 256;
    while (true)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[readSize];
        long bytesRead= rdr.GetBytes(1, startIndex, buffer, 0, readSize);
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, (int)bytesRead);
        startIndex += bytesRead;
        if (bytesRead != readSize) break;
    }
    conn.Close();
    byte[] byteArr = ms.ToArray();
    ms.Dispose();

    return byteArr;
}
```

once you retrieve the data from db, you can save it somewhere in a temp location or in your designated location.

```
    string fileToRetrieve = @"Test1.docx"; 
    var fileRetrieved = RetrieveFile(fileToRetrieve);
    string tempFile = @"C:\file\path\Retrived.docx";
    File.WriteAllBytes(tempFile, fileRetrieved);
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the file as a MemoryStream (of bytes).  Save the memorystream to your SQL table - to a column defined as VARBINARY(MAX).  to restore the file, do the same in reverse.  Plenty of info for these steps on the internet